# What does cmp %eax,0x80498d4(,%ebx,4) mean?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, gdb, att

I know there are some other questions similar to this, but I'm still having trouble understanding the () part of it. Could someone spell this syntax out for me? Thanks.

Comment: It'll be easier to understand in Intel syntax: `cmp [ebx*4 + 0x80498d4], eax`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cmp %eax,0x80498d4(,%ebx,4)
```

**cmp** is the comparison assembly instruction. It performs a comparison between two arguments by signed subtracting the right argument from the left and sets a CPU EFLAGS register. This EFLAGS register can then be used to do conditional branching / moving, etc.

**First argument:** `%eax (the value in the %eax register)

**Second argument:** 0x80498d4(,%ebx,4). This is read as `offset ( base, index, scale )` In your example, the value of the second argument is the memory location offset `0x80498d4 + base (which I believe defaults to zero if not included) + value in %ebx register * 4 (scaling factor)`.

*Note: I believe base here is empty and defaults to the value 0.*

You can take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/817-5477/ennby/index.html for more information on the syntax for Intel x86 assembly instructions.